# Compare two datatables with out primary keys. VB.net

Tags: vb.net, csv, datatable, compare

I'm on three days of searching with no luck.  I have datatable1 in access database.  I populate datatable 2 from csv file from third party.  I need to compare both datatables and update any changes or add new rows to datatable1.  DT1 can have a primary key doesn't at this time.  csv file doesn't have primary key and datatable 2 needs to be cleared after updating datatable 1.  Merge getchanges method will not work since there isn't a primary key.  Need suggestions on how to do this.

Let me see if I can make this as short as possible.  I have data from a site that I can only get in csv files.  There are three csv files Purchase Orders, Packages, and shipments.  As POs get completed and paid the site dumps the data.  I need to be able to pull this data in and retain for my purposes.  So where I am at now is that I have an access data base with 6 tables.  3 permanent and 3 temp tables. The temp tables are cleaned with each import of csv file.  I need to compare the temp table and update/add to the permanent tables.  Package and shipments have a field that is unique and I can set as a primary key.  PO does not.  There are three columns that would need to be combined to make a unique primary key Purchase order, Line number, Line Shipment number.  I cannont get merge getchanges to work on Packages or shipments returns null and the lack of primary key that method won't work on PO.  Let me know if this is confusing I'll try to get more detailed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... How do you merge / what columns are you comparing to know how to compare one table with the other??

Comment: What i have so far is i have a temp table I load the csv file into.  Then I have the database table(access).  Both tables have the same schema but the data in the temp table changes day to day.  I need to compare and update/add changes to the database table but since the csv generated table doesn't have primary keys the merge and getchanges doesn't work.

Comment: Why not add primary keys to both tables based upon the columns you use to match them?

Comment: I wish that would work.  The csv file is from our customer and as time goes by items will fall off(be removed) and the primary keys will end up not matching.  That is why I am storing to database instead of just reading csv into an in memory data table.  We want to retain a history.

Comment: ... I'm really confused here - How are you going to code your comparison, then, to decide how to update Table1?

Comment: I was hoping to check all column values in one row if exact match move on.  If not all match update the ones that are different.  If not there at all add the entire row.

Comment: ... You're in a tough position - You have to figure out which row form Table1 to compare with which row from Table2 and since you're checking item-by-item, you'll probably have to do the actual comparison in a loop... BUT I'm still saying that the way you decide which rows to compare one-against-the-other, you'll have a primary key macthing relationship... Fact of the matter is I'm thinking you **HAVE** to figure out the table relationship for comparisin's sake and, from that point you could do a merge...

Comment: Not to make it more confusing but this is on 3 different sets of data.  Two sets I could make a field in both primary but on the third it would take 3 columns as primary.  None of the 3 columns are unique on there one but together they would be.  Still merge getdata is still returning null on the two with primary added.

Comment: Please update your question with simple examples of the data... I'd love to help, but it's not making any sense any more

Comment: Is your problem similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984732/vb-net-custom-merging-for-datatables? Can you make some example tables like  him?